# VBA: Offset with cells position

Tags: vba, runtime-error, offset

I have been searching, and the Offset only can be fixed (http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_offset_property.html)?

I would like to know how to do a variable offset. For example, I choose a fixed value from worksheet (1), based on the condition that you can see below it will do the offset, and use the offset value in a formula from code of worksheet (2).

Worksheet 1: I have the columns A to H and row 1

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
1    5         10        15        20
```

Worksheet 2: I have column B and rows 14 to 18. In this worksheet, the values 2,3,4,5,6 are random and are used to determine the number of columns to offset in the worksheet 1. As follows, I expressed what I am trying to do, may be its easier to understand.

```
Row                   B                             
 14    2  Sheets(1).Offset(A1,0,($B2-$B$2)*2,1,1)= Offset(5,0,(2-2)*2,1,1) =5 (A1)
 15    3  Sheets(1).Offset(A1,0,($B3-$B$2)*2,1,1)= Offset(5,0,(3-2)*2,1,1) =10 (C1)
 16    4  Sheets(1).Offset(A1,0,($B4-$B$2)*2,1,1)= Offset(5,0,(4-2)*2,1,1) =15 (E1)
 17    5  Sheets(1).Offset(A1,0,($B5-$B$2)*2,1,1)= Offset(5,0,(5-2)*2,1,1) =20 (G1)
 18    6  Sheets(1).Offset(A1,0,($B6-$B$2)*2,1,1)= Offset(5,0,(6-2)*2,1,1) =0 (I1)
```

During my search, I only found possible to do an offset by placing numbers of rows and columns desired to offset. However, it does not work for me.

Since the following code, returns time error '1004, I would like to know why? Is not supposed to return a value? If everything is defined, why does the offset not working? What's wrong?

```
Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Offset(0,(Cells(i+countRows,3) - Cells(i,3))*2))
```

How can I solve this error?

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's not so clear what you are trying to achieve ? could you show your worksheets and draw on them what kind of reference you want to get ?

Comment: at what column in "Worksheet 2" you have the values `2` , `3`, `4`, `5`, `6` ? where do you want to have the result ? Column C ?

Comment: Shai Rado, actually I want to get the value into a formula that is in the code, where the result of the formula will be printed in worksheet 2.

Comment: sorry, but i'm not following you. how will you get the value in Cell B2 into a formula that later is used to overwrite the value in cell B2 ?

Comment: I am sorry if I am not explaining properly. The offset is not in a cell. I gave it as an example to understand how to do in the general case. I just need to understand why my code is not working since the offset in a formula will depend on the general values (2, 3, 4, 5, 6). Where 2-2= 0* 2 (is the offset for the first case), 3-2 = 1*2 (the offset for the second), 4-2=2*2 (the offset for third) and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138451/discussion-between-shai-rado-and-vbalearner).